# Validation error when publishing customization containing Smartsheet SDK reference

Tags: acumatica, smartsheet-api

I have an Acumatica customization that uses a third-party (Smartsheet) API reference.  This works fine in a development environment - even re-publishing the customization project - but when it's packaged up and deployed on another instance, I get the following error:

[image]

Not sure if anyone would have any suggestions on what might possibly cause this error, but I just thought I'd check...

Thanks

Comment: Did you include the DLL in your "Files" tab of the customization project so that it is ported to the other instance?

Comment: The third party's dll is in the references of the Visual Studio project, and the customization project's dll is included in the customization project's 'Files'...  Do I need to include the third party dlls in the 'Files' tab as well?

Comment: Pretty sure that depends on whether the DLL is installed on the other instance in some other way.  If it is in the BIN folder for your project, then I think you have to include it in your project's file list.  Otherwise, how does the 3rd party DLL make it over to the other instance?  To be honest, I'm just thinking basics here but have no personal experience with this specific error.  It does, however, seem the message is telling you that the project is expecting to need to load a DLL, but it can't find it.  Worst case, give it a try and let me know.

Comment: That did it, Brian.  I answered my own question, but gave you credit..  Thanks again.  ;D

Comment: Unfortunately, I jumped the gun on thinking this was solved.  Apparently, I need all the third party files, but Acumatica doesn't see them when trying to include them in the 'Files' section of the Customization Manager.  Not sure how to get them in there.

Comment: Not certain, but I think you may be able to just drop it in the bin directory to get it to show up.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you have to include all dependent dlls for the third party API in the Acumatica Customization  project's 'Files' section, even though they're compiled as references in the Acumatica customization project's Visual Studio project.

Thanks to Brian Stevens (above) for his answer and making me realize this...